# python loop not calling function second time

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision, dlib

Below code is gives pose estimation for a 'face' in a video. I have modified the code to take a folder/directory as input and expect it to process all videos in the directory.
  Using below code I am expecting all videos in a folder to be processed but 'for' loop will only process one video and not others, below is the loop and it will call parse_video only once.

```
    if args.videoDirPath is not None:
    for videoName in os.listdir(folderName):
        print(videoName)
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(videoName)
        parse_video(video)
```

**Folder(videoFolder) has following videos:**

```
amir.mp4
arnab-srk.mp4
kanihya.mp4
simma.mp4
salman.mp4
```

**output**

```
opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:207: UserWarning: The use of 
the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, please use transforms.Resize 
instead.
warnings.warn("The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, " +

simma.mp4
frameNumber : 1
amir.mp4
creating...output/frame1.jpg
creating...output/frame2.jpg
creating...output/frame3.jpg
creating...output/frame4.jpg
creating...output/frame5.jpg
frameNumber : 6
arnab-srk.mp4
frameNumber : 6
kanihya.mp4
frameNumber : 6
salman.mp4
frameNumber : 6
```

**Output folder: has following videos and text file:**

```
     output-out-1.avi
     output-out-6.avi
     output-out.txt  # blank
```

I run the program using following parameters

```
!python code/test_on_video_dlib.py --snapshot hopenet_alpha1.pkl --face_model mmod_human_face_detector.dat --directoryPath videoFolder --output_string out --n_frames 20 --fps 200enter code here
```

Code for 'test_on_video_dlib.py'

```
  import sys, os, argparse
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import torch
  import torch.nn as nn
  from torch.autograd import Variable
  from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
  from torchvision import transforms
  import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
  import torchvision
  import torch.nn.functional as F
  from PIL import Image
  import datasets, hopenet, utils
  from skimage import io
  import dlib
  import face_alignment
  import numpy as np
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from skimage import io

  def parse_video(video,nr):       

      # New cv2
      width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))   # float
      height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) # float

      # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')

      out = cv2.VideoWriter('output/video/output-{}-{}.avi'.format(args.output_string, nr), fourcc, 
                  args.fps, (width, height))
      #frame_num = 1

      frame_num = nr # add nr here also

      while frame_num <= args.n_frames:
          #print frame_num
          ret,frame = video.read()
          if ret == False:
              break            
          #writing frames
          name = 'output/frame' + str(frame_num) + '.jpg'
          print("creating..." +name)
          cv2.imwrite(name,frame)        
          cv2_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
          # Dlib detect
          dets = cnn_face_detector(cv2_frame, 1)

          for idx, det in enumerate(dets):
            # Get x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, conf
            x_min = det.rect.left()
            y_min = det.rect.top()
            x_max = det.rect.right()
            y_max = det.rect.bottom()
            conf = det.confidence

            if conf > 1.0:
                bbox_width = abs(x_max - x_min)
                bbox_height = abs(y_max - y_min)
                x_min -= 2 * bbox_width / 4
                x_max += 2 * bbox_width / 4
                y_min -= 3 * bbox_height / 4
                y_max += bbox_height / 4
                x_min = max(x_min, 0); y_min = max(y_min, 0)
                x_max = min(frame.shape[1], x_max); y_max = min(frame.shape[0], y_max)
                # Crop image
                img = cv2_frame[int(y_min):int(y_max),int(x_min):int(x_max)]
                img = Image.fromarray(img)

                # Transform
                img = transformations(img)
                img_shape = img.size()
                img = img.view(1, img_shape[0], img_shape[1], img_shape[2])
                img = Variable(img).cuda(gpu)

                yaw, pitch, roll = model(img)

                yaw_predicted = F.softmax(yaw,dim=1)
                pitch_predicted = F.softmax(pitch,dim=1)
                roll_predicted = F.softmax(roll,dim=1)
                # Get continuous predictions in degrees.
                yaw_predicted = torch.sum(yaw_predicted.data[0] * idx_tensor) * 3 - 99
                pitch_predicted = torch.sum(pitch_predicted.data[0] * idx_tensor) * 3 - 99
                roll_predicted = torch.sum(roll_predicted.data[0] * idx_tensor) * 3 - 99
                txt_out.write(('output/frame' + str(frame_num) + '.jpg') + ' %f %f %f\n' % (yaw_predicted, pitch_predicted,       roll_predicted))
                # utils.plot_pose_cube(frame, yaw_predicted, pitch_predicted, roll_predicted, (x_min + x_max) / 2, (y_min + y_max) / 2, size = bbox_width)
                utils.draw_axis(frame, yaw_predicted, pitch_predicted, roll_predicted, tdx = (x_min + x_max) / 2, tdy= (y_min + y_max) / 2, size = bbox_height/2)
                # Plot expanded bounding box
                # cv2.rectangle(frame, (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (0,255,0), 1)

       out.write(frame)
       frame_num += 1

  out.release()
  video.release()
  return frame_num

  def parse_args():
      """Parse input arguments."""
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Head pose estimation using the Hopenet network.')
      parser.add_argument('--gpu', dest='gpu_id', help='GPU device id to use [0]',
        default=0, type=int)
      parser.add_argument('--snapshot', dest='snapshot', help='Path of model snapshot.',
      default='', type=str)
      parser.add_argument('--face_model', dest='face_model', help='Path of DLIB face detection model.',
      default='', type=str)
      parser.add_argument('--video', dest='video_path', help='Path of video')
      #code to pass video folder name
      parser.add_argument('--directoryPath',dest='videoDirPath' ,help="directory path containing all videos")
      parser.add_argument('--output_string', dest='output_string', help='String appended to output file')
      parser.add_argument('--n_frames', dest='n_frames', help='Number of frames', type=int)
      parser.add_argument('--fps', dest='fps', help='Frames per second of source video', type=float, default=30.)
      args = parser.parse_args()
      return args

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      args = parse_args()
      cudnn.enabled = True

      batch_size = 1
      gpu = args.gpu_id
      snapshot_path = args.snapshot
      out_dir = 'output/video'
      video_path = args.video_path
      #folder path code
      folderName = args.videoDirPath

      if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
          os.makedirs(out_dir)

      # ResNet50 structure
      model = hopenet.Hopenet(torchvision.models.resnet.Bottleneck, [3, 4, 6, 3], 66)

      # Dlib face detection model
      cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1(args.face_model)

      #print 'Loading snapshot.'
      # Load snapshot
      saved_state_dict = torch.load(snapshot_path)
      model.load_state_dict(saved_state_dict)

      #print 'Loading data.'

      transformations = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale(224),
      transforms.CenterCrop(224), transforms.ToTensor(),
      transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

      model.cuda(gpu)

      #print 'Ready to test network.'

      # Test the Model
       model.eval()  # Change model to 'eval' mode (BN uses moving mean/var).
      total = 0

      idx_tensor = [idx for idx in range(66)]
      idx_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(idx_tensor).cuda(gpu)

      if args.video_path is not None:
              video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
              parse_video(video)
      # THIS IS THE LOOP I AM REFERRING IN QUESTION   
      nr=1 
      if args.videoDirPath is not None:
         for videoName in os.listdir(folderName):
             print(videoName)
             video = cv2.VideoCapture(videoName)
             nr = parse_video(video ,nr)
```

**Expected output:**

I want each video in videoFolder to be processed and its frame should be created in output folder.

Comment: fixed indentation issues,,

Comment: you have to use full path for files - `folderName/videoName`. Now you use only `videoName` so it is looking for file in current working folder.

Comment: @furas Please refer to output section, It prints all video files in the folder, so its correct. I want to pass a folder name and it should process all videos in it, its already working for a single video with different parameters if I pass folderName/VideoName

Comment: your code display files which you have `folderName` but later it uses only `videoName` without `folderName` to open it - so it try to open file from current folder, not from folder `folderName`. You have to add `folderName` to `videoName` or you have to change folder `cd folderName`

Comment: as you said - in old version you pass `folderName/videoname` - so you had `cv2.VideoCapture(folderName/videoName)` but new code pass only `videoName` so you have `cv2.VideoCapture(videoName)`. `listdir(folderName)` gives file names without `folderName`.

Comment: add some prints in the function to find out which parts are reached and what kind if variable values are present. What is the meaning of "nr"? is it not 'resetted' for further calls?

Answer (score 0):

As for me you have to use correct path to file - `folderName/videoName`

```
for videoName in os.listdir(folderName):

    videoName = os.path.join(folderName, videoName)  

    print(videoName)
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(videoName)
```